# Transforming and merging event time data in R

Tags: r, merge, transformation, survival-analysis

Let's say I have a data.frame of some event time data as such

```
> example_data
  id start.f stop.f status.f start.r1 stop.r1 status.r1 start.r2 stop.r2 status.r2
1  1      0   10.0        1     0.00    2.00         1     0.00    1.00         1
2  1      0   10.0        1     2.00    5.00         1     1.00    3.00         1
3  1      0   10.0        1     5.00    8.00         1     3.00    6.00         1
4  1      0   10.0        1     8.00   10.00         0     6.00   10.00         0
5  2      0   10.9        1     0.00    2.18         1     0.00    1.09         1
6  2      0   10.9        1     2.18    5.45         1     1.09    3.27         1
7  2      0   10.9        1     5.45    8.72         1     3.27    6.54         1
8  2      0   10.9        1     8.72   10.90         0     6.54   10.90         0
```

For a specific analysis I want to transform the data above into a data.frame as such (only done for one ID in the example below):

```
> transformed_example_data
  id start stop status.f status.r1 status.r2 strata
1  1     0    1       0        0        1      1
2  1     1    2       0        1        0      2
3  1     2    3       0        0        1      3
4  1     3    5       0        1        0      4
5  1     5    6       0        0        1      5
6  1     6    8       0        1        0      6
7  1     8   10       1        0        0      7
```

As you can see, the 'start' / 'stop' variables got merged and sorted. The 'status' variables with their respective suffix indicate whether the event happened. 'strata' is a simple enumeration of the events per individual.

I tried to use pivot_longer from the tidyverse but can`t seem to properly understand it's functionality or find an apporiate example from where I can adapt.

I can`t seem to wrap my head around how to do this and would kindly ask for help.
The solution is ideally performant as I have huge datasets which need to go through this procedure.

Might be important of note that there can never be two events at the same. The suffix 'f' indicates the fatal event type, 'r1' and 'r2' are each recurrent event types.